# Emoji and symbols input panel weird behavior

Tags: keyboard, macos, bug, internationalization

I am talking about the text input panel `Emoji and symbols` that could be opened thorough <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

It could be opened as a *bubble*:

[image]

or as a *window*:

[image]

The problem is only in the *bubble* mode: when I try to select an emoji (or special char), the *bubble body* automatically slides at the top while clicking and so this will *force* me select another unwanted emoji.

This happens only at the first click.

I encountered the same problem with Sierra and on two different Macs.

See this [video](https://youtu.be/iIWzpkkPqkc) for further details.

**Please note that:**

• in this video I clicked for three emojis. First and third attempts demonstrate the bug (dog and snow man), the second (cat) doesn't instead,

• this happens in every Apps such as Telegram, TextEdit, Safari, ... .

Probably it's a bug. There's some workaround?

Comment: Does this happen in all apps including TextEdit, Notes, Mail, 
Safari?

Comment: Yes, it happens everywhere. Now add this info in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Only use the windowed version :) Are you using a trackpad or a mouse?

Comment: Both mouse or trackpad, indifferently.